# Google app engine PHP SDK with laravel4 unknow error

Tags: google-app-engine, laravel-4

I'm beginer with GAE. I'm trying to use it with laravel4 but i get tis weird error.

**Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
PHP Startup: apc_fcntl_create: could not open C:\windows.apc.a03388**

Can some one explain this to me?

I'm using this tutorial
https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/2013/10/22/getting-started-with-laravel-on-php-for-app-engine/

Thank you

Comment: Can you add a complete stack trace to your question?

Answer (score 0):

To simplify things, you might want to start with laravel pre-configured to run on App Engine - see https://github.com/ajessup/laravel